# look for match from a different array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a base array like this

```
base_array=[0,3,5]
```

There is a

```
second_array=[4,5,6,0,5,4]
```

What I want is create a new array from `second_array` but filter out the values missing in `base_array`

So new array will look like this

```
new_array=[5,0,5]
```

How can I do this in ruby?
Thank you.

Comment: `second_array.select { |i| base_array.include? i }` which is quite semantic.

Comment: You say the new array should be `[0,5,5]`, but both answers--including the one you selected--return `[5,0,5]`. Why `[0,5,5]`? Is it `[5,0,5],sort`? Please correct or clarify with an edit. Also, this is a pure-Ruby question, so you should remove the Rails tag. Is that you in the pilot's or co-pilot's seat?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes the order doesn't matter. Good point. updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the values and don't care about number of occurences you could use the intersection:

```
base_array & second_array
=> [0, 5]
```

Otherwise just select them like this:

```
second_array.select { |v| base_array.include?(v) }
=> [5, 0, 5]
```

Comment: It's clear from the question that the OP *does* care about the number of occurrences, so why give an answer for a different question? Better to just give the second part of your answer, which is fine.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
new_array = second_array  - (second_array  - base_array )
[4,5,6,0,5,4] - ([4,5,6,0,5,4] - [0,3,5])
>> [5, 0, 5]
```